# BigQuery emulator with local instance of the Apache Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow

I'm working on a project for integration different data sources into Google BigQuery.
It is the batch approach.
We are using Apache Airflow for orchestration.

Simplified flow is: create raw tables (predefined DDL) -> call python code to do batch insert (via bq python client) -> trigger different SQL for transformations -> end

For testing purposes, we're using the GCP dev project.

But, recently, I found BigQuery Emulator: [BigQuery Emulator](https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator).
Python client example works just fine: [BigQuery Emulator: Call endpoint from python client](https://github.com/goccy/bigquery-emulator#2-call-endpoint-from-python-client)

I'm curious about how to configure the local instance of Airflow to use this emulator. 
I didn't find a way to point `BigQueryExecuteQueryOperator` to use the emulator. We are using this operator to trigger all our SQL.

I tried to set 'gcp_conn_id' but it always fails with `"Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application. For more information, please see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started"`

As connection type I tried `HTTP` and `Google Bigquery`, no difference.

Airflow version: 2.3.4 
bigquery-emulator: 0.1.11

Comment: I think you can use the Python client in a PythonOperator, but I am thinking about a way to install the emulator on all the nodes of the Airflow’s cluster

Comment: That might work, I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the hint.